# Call a c# dll function from testcomplete with a int[] parameter

Tags: c#, arrays, com, testcomplete

I'm trying to call a c# library function from within testcomplete code.

The c# library i made based on the answer below by Helen is structured as follows: (build target for the library is 3.5 with a generic strongname key and regasm'd for both 32/64 bit)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace TestCompleteTest
{
    [Guid("122FD1AB-839F-4A3A-8A08-973A3836216B")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ProgId("ArrayTest")]
    public class ArrayTest: IArrayTest
    {
        public void ArrayFunction(int[] arrayParameter)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText("C:\arraylog.txt"))
            {
                writer.Write("\r\nLog Entry : ");
                writer.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
                    DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
                writer.WriteLine("  :");
                writer.WriteLine("  :{0}", arrayParameter.Count());
                writer.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
            }
        }
    }

    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    [Guid("00655BDE-A768-4EC0-9C9A-A903976195F2")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IArrayTest
    {
        void ArrayFunction(int[] arrayParameter);
    }
}
```

Im trying to call this function from within a TestComplete 10.40 desktop client as follows:

```
procedure ArrayTest;
var arrayTest, arrType, arrayOfIntegers;
begin    
  arrayTest := Sys.OleObject('ArrayTest');  
  //Create array type
  arrType := dotNET.System.Type.GetType('System.Int32');
  //Create array
  arrayOfIntegers := dotNET.System.Array.CreateInstance(arrType, 5);
  //Fill array
  arrayOfIntegers.SetValue(1, 0);
  arrayOfIntegers.SetValue(2, 0);
  arrayOfIntegers.SetValue(3, 0);
  arrayOfIntegers.SetValue(4, 0);
  arrayOfIntegers.SetValue(5, 0);

  arrayTest.ArrayFunction(arrayOfIntegers);
end;
```

This still results in a Exception with the message "The parameter is incorrect" on the following line in the testcomplete function.:
**arrayTest.ArrayFunction(arrayOfIntegers);**

Any further help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What version of Delphi? Only one version had .NET.

Comment: We cannot see any of your interop. We've no idea how you are exposing the managed code to Delphi. Looks like late bound COM.

Comment: @JerryDodge It's interop. No version of Delphi "had .net". Many versions of Delphi had a Delphi compiler that output .net assemblies.

Comment: It's not Delphi, it's DelphiScript in TestComplete (an automated testing tool).

Comment: @Helen Thanks. I've re-tagged. And upvoted your answer!

Comment: You should access your assembly via `dotNET` rather than `Sys.OleObject`; see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestComplete DelphiScript is an [ActiveScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Scripting)-based language (like Windows Script Host's VBScript and JScript) and uses the Variant data type. While simple values like numbers, booleans and strings are marshalled into .NET correctly, "complex" values like arrays and enums need to be created on the .NET side using the `dotNET` wrapper:

```pascal
...
var arrayOfIntegers, arrType, enumType, enumParameter;
begin
  // Create a .NET array, e.g. {5}
  arrType := dotNET.System.Type.GetType('System.Int32');
  arrayOfIntegers := dotNET.System.Array.CreateInstance(arrType, 1);
  arrayOfIntegers.SetValue(5, 0);

  // Create an enumeration value, e.g. DayOfWeek.Tuesday
  enumType := dotNET.System.Type.GetType('System.DayOfWeek');
  enumParameter := dotNET.System.Enum.Parse(enumType, 'Tuesday');

  functionResult := CSharpLibrary.CSharpFunction(arrayOfIntegers, enumParameter);
end;
```

---

**UPD:** There's no need to make .NET assemblies COM-visible to use them in TestComplete. You need to add your assembly to project properties > CLR Bridge instead. Then you can call the function like this:

```pascal
arrayTest := dotNET.TestCompleteTest.ArrayTest.zctor();
arrayTest.ArrayFunction(arrayOfIntegers);
```

or if `ArrayFunction` is a static method:

```
dotNET.TestCompleteTest.ArrayTest.ArrayFunction(arrayOfIntegers);
```

The docs have some more details: [Calling Functions From .NET Assemblies](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/55369/).

Also, in the [`SetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kk3bwkb0(v=vs.110).aspx) method, the 2nd parameter is the element index, so it should be:

```pascal
arrayOfIntegers.SetValue(1, 0); // value, index
arrayOfIntegers.SetValue(2, 1);
arrayOfIntegers.SetValue(3, 2);
arrayOfIntegers.SetValue(4, 3);
arrayOfIntegers.SetValue(5, 4);
```

Comment: Hi helen, Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately your suggestion did not seem to resolve my problem. i updated my original question to reflect this. any chance you could see whats going wrong?

Comment: That works flawlessly indeed, i had added the dll to CLR Bridge but didnt think to call it like that. thanks for the pointer!